# TextBox и Цвет выделения

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Нужно изменить цвет выделения текста мышью (когда зажимаешь лкм). Никак не могу найти никакой информации на данный счёт, пробовал с `RichTextBox->SelectionColor`, но это не то или я не понимаю как это использовать. Для ListBox и ComboBox я ловлю событие `DrawItem` и в нем меняю цвет `e->State ^ DrawItemState::Selected`. Для `TextBox` не могу найти `DrawItem` да и принцип выделения тут отличается, поэтому не думаю что это прокатит. Дело в том что у меня программа на скинах и много разных контроллов, как текстбоксов так и листбоксов поэтому синий цвет выделения - бельмо в глазах, нужно менять. Наткнулся на параметр `SelectionBrush` для `TextBox`, но на msdn пример только для `Xaml`, а я как то не допираю что это вообще, и как это использовать в CLI (добавил неймспейс Xaml но такого параметра для `textBox` и `RichTextBox` не появилось).
Собственно вопрос - как? или что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы так много тегов включили, что не понятно ваше приложение какую технологию использует WPF или WinForms?

Comment: winforms c++/cli

Comment: ок, сегодня после работы смогу зайти.